# HTML/PHP Checkbox not working

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" value="<?php if(isset($login_username)){ echo $login_username; } ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['login_1']; ?>"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['login_2']; ?>"></p>

    <div class="options" style="margin: 5;line-height: 1.4;">
        <a onclick="showRegister();"><?php echo $lang['login_4']; ?></a><br>
        <a onclick="lostPassword();"><?php echo $lang['login_5']; ?></a>
    </div>

    <p class="remember_me">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember" <?php if(isset($login_remember)){ if($login_remember == "on"){ echo " checked"; }} ?>><?php echo $lang['login_3']; ?></input>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="login"></input>
    <p class="submit">
       <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['login_button']; ?>">
    </p>
</form>
```

When i press the Submit button, $_POST returns: Array ( [login] => Username [password] => Password [action] => login )

But not the checkbox, anyone can help me?

EDIT:
I added: name="remember" but still not working.

Comment: @Shannon I rolled-back your edit as you removed the OP's update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with checkboxes is, the $_POST value of a checkbox is only set, if the box IS checked. If it is not, the value is not even posted. So you have to use isset() on the expected $_POST variable. If it is not set, the box is not checked. If it is set, you can evaluate the value.

Comment: You're welcome, I had the same problem once and it took me hours to find out :-)

Answer (score 7):

Add `name` too

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="login_remember" <?php if(isset($login_remember)){ if($login_remember == "on"){ echo " checked"; }} ?>><?php echo $lang['login_3']; ?></input>
```

Comment: Small addition: checkboxes do not appear in `POST` if they are not checked at the moment the form gets submitted.

Comment: correct. It seems the name should be `login_remember`. Please use `isset`, to see if it was checked